# Custom lookup field on rails 3 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So heres what I am trying to do:

I want a field that is text based, "a coupon code"

in a nested form.

So basically `f.text_field :coupon`

But that value should be a relationship to an item in a `coupons` table, but not by id.

Coupon table could look like

```
|ID| CouponCode |
+--+------------+
|1 | a89sd9asda |
+--+------------+
```

and my main table would look like

```
|ID| OrderTitle |   Coupon   |
+--+------------+------------+
|1 | sdfsdfsdfd | a89sd9asda |
+--+------------+------------+
```

Is there a way in rails to link these two via a has_one and use a non ID field?

Comment: If your coupons table only have an ID and a Code, I dont really understand why do you have this table. Just use the CouponCode in the Order table.

Comment: Yeah it has to match one of the coupons in the coupon code database tho. The coupons are pre generated, distributed, i need to match that only one order can have one coupon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :coupon_code, :foreign_key => 'CouponCode'
end

class CouponCode < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order, :foreign_key => 'CouponCode'
end
```

However, I agree with damien: this looks a bit off of the common db design approaches.

Comment: would i need to set :primary_key => "Coupon" too? since it wouldn't be using Coupon_id?